# Showing array result from JSON coldfusion

Tags: arrays, json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11

I am having a hard time with parsing JSON values. I am using deserializeJSON, and it returns (if multiple value) in array.

So far I've got:

```
<cfset test = deserializeJSON(json)>

<cfloop collection="#test.LoadResult#" item="val">
        <cfif isDefined("test.LoadResult.#val#")>
            <cfif isSimpleValue(evaluate("test.LoadResult.#val#"))>
                #val#  = #evaluate("test.LoadResult.#val#")# <br>
                <cfif !isSimpleValue("#test.LoadResult.BankAccounts#")>
                    #ArrayToList(test.LoadResult.ArrayWithMultipleData)# 
                </cfif>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

But when i try to display returned array, it gives me error "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.".

Question is, how to display all values in json, whenever it's multiple values(in array) or just simplevalue ?

Comment: can you post some of your json file?

Comment: As @MattBusche said - you can't tell the problem from the code above. Do `<cfdump var="#test#">` and then post those results - then we can see how CF is deserializing. The raw JSON might be useful as well.

Comment: http://imgur.com/r8f9PYf -> This is the json structure

Comment: I don't see "LoadResult" in that json structure.

Comment: Screen shots and samples belong in the question, where there are more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Just using something like `<cfdump var="#test#">`? I may not be understanding your question. However, I personally like to edit my queries using some javascript with this sort of method:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        mydata = eval(<cfoutput>#jsondata#</cfoutput>);
        var output = document.getElementById('someDiv');
        var colMap = new Object();
        //first - find my columnsco
        for(var i = 0; i < mydata.COLUMNS.length; i++) {
          colMap[mydata.COLUMNS[i]] = i;      
        } //start customizing the display based on your query/json data
        for(var i = 0; i < mydata.DATA.length; i++) {
           var str ="";`enter code here`
           str += mydata.DATA[i][colMap["COLUMN_NAME"]] + " "; 
        }
        output.innerHTML += str; //this can go in the for loop, depending on your requirements
       </script>
```